# Cannot install Cassandra 2.X in travis-ci

Tags: cassandra, travis-ci, cassandra-2.2

I am having issues create a build with cassandra as a service with a version that is higher than 2.X (let x be higher than 1).

I have verified that

```
services:
   - cassandra
```

produce a cassandra 2.0.9 as i put in my `.travis.yml`

```
$ cqlsh --execute="show version" 127.0.0.1
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.9 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

However my project requires 2.2.4 as a minimum.

when i tried doing as per travis suggested:

```
before_install:
  - sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*
  - wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/2.2.4/apache-cassandra-2.2.4-bin.tar.gz && tar -xvzf apache-cassandra-2.2.4-bin.tar.gz && sudo sh apache-cassandra-2.2.4/bin/cassandra
  - sleep 30
```

It fails to boot the cassandra as it waits at the following line:

```
Connection error: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:9160
```

While dumping the raw_log it gets stuck here:

```
INFO  16:01:31 Loading org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@2716f853[cfId=5f2fbdad-91f1-3946-bd25-d5da3a5c35ec,ksName=system_auth,cfName=resource_role_permissons_index,cfType=Standard,comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),comment=index of db roles with permissions granted on a resource,readRepairChance=0.0,dcLocalReadRepairChance=0.0,gcGraceSeconds=7776000,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxCompactionThreshold=32,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING_COLUMN, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=resource, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}],compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy,compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionParameters={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor},bloomFilterFpChance=0.01,memtableFlushPeriod=3600000,caching={"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"},defaultTimeToLive=0,minIndexInterval=128,maxIndexInterval=2048,speculativeRetry=99.0PERCENTILE,droppedColumns={},triggers=[],isDense=false]
INFO  16:01:31 Initializing system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get travis to successful build a cassandra 2.X higher than its default?

**NOTES**:

- My project is PHP base.
- I have tried this in Container mode and as
  sudo (as per travis instructions also